# OpenLdap Configuration Issue

Tags: debian, authentication, openldap, redmine

For the last few days I've been desperately reading official/user made guides in order to properly configure my openldap to allow users to login to a project management webapp (namely Redmine). With that said, please let me share the basic setup of the environment i'm dealing with.

Webapplication(s):

> Redmine,
>   Phpldapadmin

LDAP:

> Openldap

After the installation, i took the following steps to re-configure my ldap to reflect better the ldap being used in production (since this whole redmine + ldap isn't in production yet)

1. Stopped slapd service and removed the **cn=config.ldif** from **/etc/ldap/slapd.d**
2. Modified **/usr/share/slapd/slapd.conf** to this:

   ```
   include         /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
   include         /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
   include         /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema
   include         /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema

   pidfile         /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
   argsfile        /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
   loglevel        none

   modulepath  /usr/lib/ldap
   moduleload  back_mdb

   sizelimit 500
   tool-threads 1

   backend     mdb
   database        mdb
   suffix          "o=testcompany.com"
   rootdn          "cn=admin,o=testcompany.com"
   directory       "/var/lib/tc-ldap"
   rootpw          "password"

   index           objectClass eq
   index       uid eq
   index       ou eq
   index       default eq,sub

   lastmod         on
   checkpoint      512 30

   access to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
           by dn="cn=admin,o=testcompany.com" write
           by anonymous auth
           by self write
           by * none

   access to dn.base="" by * read

   access to *
           by dn="cn=admin,o=testcompany.com" write
           by * read
   ```
3. Afterwards, **slaptest -f /usr/share/slapd/slapd.conf -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d** which generated my new **cn=config.ldif**
4. Set the appropriate user/group to the new **cn=config.ldif** with **chown -R openldap:openldap /etc/ldap/slapd.d/**
5. Fired up slapd service and checked if the ldap was running or not. Since it was and i could access it with phpldapadmin, i added an **organizationalUnit (ou=sales)**, all the country codes and imported 3000 users (by using **ldapadd**) Now my DIT looks as follows

   ```
   - o=testcompany.com
     - ou=sales
       - AD
         + uid=123456,c=AD,ou=sales,o=testcompany.com
         + ...
   ```

   which is great, this is exactly the way it should look like, however I've noticed, that **cn=admin,o=testcompany.com** entry doesn't exists, while it did using the default config after i've installed openldap.
6. In Redmine, I've configured and tested the **ldap authentication**. It is working correctly (it can both connect to my ldap and If i wish to add a new user and choose the before configured ldap authentication for it, i can even choose from the entries that are in my ldap, which is also great)
7. However (this is where my problem is) when i try to log into Redmine with a user that i've just created (with ldap authentication) i always get **Invalid credentials** error (while it works like a charm when i login with any other account, created with **Simple Authentication**)

These events led me to believe that the error is in the LDAP configuration. After a few more hours/days of fooling around with the **ACL**s and **dpkg-reconfigure slapd** (and even purging-reinstalling slapd and ldap-utils) i still can not get beyond this point. And one more bit of information, after **dpkg-reconfigure slapd** and creating a few users under the default **dc=example,dc=com**, i can get them to log into Redmine just fine (and even **cn=admin,o=testcompany.com** shows up...).

Below i'll attach a few things that I've tried. I hope someone can aid me with a few tips as to where i got off the trail (somehow i feel that i'm missing the obvious here).

What I have tried so far:

```
    1. modify the default slapd.conf file, and repeat the process i've written above
    2. create a completely new one 
    3. a lot of different ways to add/modify the ACL
    4. read through a lot of mailing list, similar problems on redmine forums, and openldap mailing lists, still no success (i can paste a lot of links from my .txt if you need it)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what the problem was.

First of all, i forgot to include the indexes: **objectClass** and **mail** in my **slapd.conf** and this was one of the reasons.

Second of all, for some reasons even if i reconfigured my ldap (and reindexed it as well) my changes wouldn't show.

As it turns out, after step **5.** (after starting the service) it's also necessary to **reload** your slapd service `sudo service slapd reload` or (`sudo service slapd force-reload` if necessary) in order for slapd to catch up with the changes.

This solved my issue. now everyone can authenticate using ldap auth :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your root dn to use dc=testcompany,dc=com
delete the dot '.'
The dot '.' is a separator for a different part of the ldap DN
specification
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1779#section-2.2
also try specifying ldapv3 in your slapd.conf file
which recognizes the o= as ou=
https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc3494.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the links, they really helped. It's possible to specify the root DSE this way as well (and we also had to, since it's how it is in the ldap we have in production)

Answer (score 0):

I would point you to a good write on the Ubuntu site - [ldapguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html)

But I would output two users one that is working and one that is not and look at the difference.  I think that you will find that the password is not set.  Could you output that?

Comment: dear @jhoskins98 the passwords were set.